# broadcast receiver and music

Tags: android, sms, media-player

I've created a simple `BroadcastReceiver` which react on `SMS` received.

One message should be able to start an alarm and another one to stop it. The alarm is triggered with a `mediaPlayer` and works well. But I can't stop it. I know that a new instance of `mediaplayer` is created each time the right `SMS` is received but even with a singleton, I can't make it work...

Here is a code snippet :

```
Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage [] messages = null;
String strMessage = "";

if (myBundle != null)
{
    Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
    messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
    {
        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
    }

    if (strMessage.equals("ATELIO&SON")){
        if(onoff == 1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Démarrage localisation sonore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        playSound();
        }
    }
    else if(strMessage.equals("ATELIO&SON&FIN")){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Fin localisation sonore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        stopSound();
    }
}
```

`playsound()` and `stopsound()` are two really simple method, the first one starting the sound and the second one checking if `mediaplayer` is `null` and acting accordingly.

Comment: your instance of mediaplayer probably isn't kept between 2 sms. that's because the context of a BR is very weak and disappears as soon as the end of the method is reached. you probably need a sticky service to keep the instance and make sure it doesn't goes away. The strange part is that the sound keeps playing while there is no reference to it, which is dangerous. Did you try to make the reference static ? (it should not disappear while the app is not flushed for memory reclaim)

Comment: A static reference did the trick! Thanks !

Comment: however, be careful with that approach. I'm not sure the static ref will retain all the context and keep the whole app alive. It is possible your app gets collected if memory lacks.

Comment: I will njzk2, the app is still on test and I'm trying different lead. Thanks !